# Access ejabberd remotely

Tags: java, ejabberd

I have two servers both running on different physical machines. On one server I am running Ejabberd and on other server I am running a web server. On the web server I am creating a page where user can register to my system. One part of this registration is to create an account in Ejabberd. I can use ejabberdctrl utility to create user accounts and I will be calling this from my java code. There are two approaches to do this (ASAIK) (I will be doing all this in my java code)

1) Install ejabberd on the system where I am running web server and use ejabberdctrl utility of local system to connect and run all commands on remote ejabberd server. In this case local ejabberd server will not be configured or running, I just need ejabberdctrl utility here. 2) Create ssh session to the remote system and access ejabberdctrl of the remote server.

Personally I like the first approach but please provide your expert opinion which approach is better and if there is any other way to achieve this please let me. I can not merge both system on one system, so thats not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend executing ejabberdctl. It is reasonable only for small-user server.

Other options

1) Use authentication using ODBC : Your web server and ejabberd can share same users table.

2) Activate mod_register_web : This module supports web api for user management. You can call via HTTP from your web server.

Comment: Thanks Keewon for your Answer.. I have read documentation and tried to configure mod_register_web module into the Ejabberd server.. I have seen that mod_register_web.beam is already there in (/usr/lib/ejabberd/ebin). I have updated configurations only as mentioned on http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_register_web/trunk/README.txt then tried navigate url http://localhost:5281/new/ and found the error Connection was reset.. Can you please help me on this.. thanks in advance for your cooperation in this regard..

Comment: Let me know your ejabberd version and ejabberd log

Comment: Thanks Keewon for your prompt response.. I am able to configure mod_register_web module and it is working fine as it is required. Currently I am looking how to enable security on it because it is available on public domain name but i want to restrict with domain name with username and password.. If you can help then I will be really thankful to you in this regard.

Comment: I think setting ACL on OS is better, if your servers have static IP.